# Logic in this method?

Tags: java, sql, arrays, sorting, stack

I am creating a java application to generate questions, and the method shown below is used to generate the questions. I have used a stack to order these questions by how many times they have appeared in the loop.
My problem is that it keeps producing multiple questions which are the same, which this method should prevent.

```
   public ArrayList<String> generateQuestions(String transcript, String className, int classYear, String classGroup) {
    ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> tags = new ArrayList<String>();

    //get tags from the database
    Statement stmt = null;
    try {
        stmt = handler.getConnection().createStatement();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if(stmt != null){
        try {
            String result = "";
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT tags.TagName FROM class, tags, questtag, questions, questclass WHERE questtag.QuestionID = questions.QuestionID AND tags.TagID = questtag.TagID AND questions.QuestionID = questclass.QuestionID AND questclass.ClassID = class.ClassID AND class.ClassName ='"+className+"' AND class.ClassYear="+classYear+" AND class.ClassGroup ='"+classGroup+"' GROUP BY tags.TagID");

            while (rs.next()) {
                result = rs.getString(1);
                tags.add(result);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    Stack<Question> stack = new Stack<Question>();
    for (String word : transcript.split("\\s+")) {
        if(  ! word.equalsIgnoreCase("the") || ! word.equalsIgnoreCase("I")) {
            for(String tag : tags) {
                if(word.equalsIgnoreCase(tag)) {
                    try {
                        stmt = handler.getConnection().createStatement();
                    } catch (SQLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    if(stmt != null){
                        try {
                            String result = "";
                            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT questions.Question FROM class, tags, questtag, questions, questclass WHERE questtag.QuestionID = questions.QuestionID AND tags.TagID = questtag.TagID AND questions.QuestionID = questclass.QuestionID AND questclass.ClassID = class.ClassID AND class.ClassName ='"+className+"' AND class.ClassYear="+classYear+" AND class.ClassGroup ='"+classGroup+"' AND tags.TagName = '"+tag+"'");
                            while (rs.next()) {
                                result = rs.getString(1);
                                Stack<Question> searchStack = new Stack<Question>();
                                boolean multiple = false;
                                if(stack.isEmpty()) { //1st question we've come to
                                    Question question = new Question(result);
                                    stack.push(question);
                                } else {
                                    while(multiple == false && !stack.isEmpty()) {
                                        //search through the stack
                                        searchStack.push(stack.pop());
                                        //if question is not already in the stack
                                        if(((Question)searchStack.peek()).getQuestion().equalsIgnoreCase(result)) {
                                            //then it is multiple
                                            //add one to its noOfTimes
                                            ((Question)searchStack.peek()).addToNoOfTimes();
                                            //order this above others with lower score
                                            if(!stack.isEmpty()) {
                                                if(((Question)stack.peek()).getNoOfTimes() < ((Question)searchStack.peek()).getNoOfTimes()) {
                                                    Question thisQuestion = searchStack.pop();
                                                    while(((Question)stack.peek()).getNoOfTimes() < thisQuestion.getNoOfTimes() && !stack.isEmpty()) {
                                                        searchStack.push(stack.pop());
                                                }
                                                stack.push(thisQuestion);
                                            } else {
                                                stack.push(searchStack.pop());
                                            }
                                        }
                                        multiple = true;
                                    }

                                }

                                while(!searchStack.empty())
                                    stack.push(searchStack.pop());
                                if(multiple == false) {
                                    Question question = new Question(result);
                                    stack.push(question);
                                } 
                                }
                            }
                        } catch (SQLException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        Stack<Question> reorderStack = new Stack<Question>();
                        while(!stack.empty()) {
                            reorderStack.push(stack.pop());
                        }
                        while(!reorderStack.empty()) {
                            Question thisQuestion = reorderStack.pop();
                            results.add(thisQuestion.getQuestion());
                            stack.push(thisQuestion);
                        }
                    }


                }
            }
        }
    }

    return results;
}
```

Comment: Nowhere in the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) does it say that it doesn't allow duplicates

Comment: @Neijwiert no, the way that I have implemented the stack/the method, I shouldn't be seeing duplicates, this is what I wanted help with, to see whether my logic through this method is ok. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: Methods do not cost money, so you can safely use more than one. Just sayin'...

Comment: @Tobb true true

Comment: I don't think this is the underlying issue, but the statement `! word.equalsIgnoreCase("the") || ! word.equalsIgnoreCase("I")` will always return true, so that `if` statement is redundant.